# How could you calculate the distance between multiple associated points, specifically a list of structures serving specific addresses within CartoDB?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, distance

I have loaded two point datasets into CartoDB. The first is a list of structures serving specific addresses, each structure has a unique code associated to it as well as the location of the structure itself. The other point dataset is a list of the addresses and their locations, each address having the code of the structure that serves it.

I know how to calculate the distance of each structure from each address, however this seems quite inefficient when all I require is the distance between the structure serving the address in question (the other structures I'm not worried about for any given address).

Note I only require the great circle (haversine) distance. Also, if the same query can determine which of the addresses lie X distance (in km) away from the structure serving it that would be great.

Any ideas on how you'd go about this within CartoDB/PostgreSQL?

Comment: Can you share the code of what you already did?

Comment: Share our table schemas. Or sample schemas. Or, `CREATE TABLE` statements. Something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Connect with Lines`](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/connect-with-lines) BUILDER analysis:

- First, add this analysis to the `structures` layer.
- Secondly, set the `addresses` layer as `TARGET`.
- Third, select `All to all` option.
- Fourth, group by the common field (unique code). Apply.

A new `length` column will be added to your layer. You can export the results or add some widgets to gain more insights. [I have built a simple map](https://team.carto.com/u/ramirocartodb/builder/fc233a2d-9f92-4a1f-a4b2-676092686328/embed) to show the result with country capitals as `structures` and the rest of cities as `addresses` using `populated_places` dataset from the Data Library.

[image: builder-map]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
SELECT *, ST_Distance(a.point, s.point)
FROM addresses AS a
JOIN structure AS s
  ON a.serviced_by_structure = s.serviced_by_structure
  AND ST_DWithin(a.point,s.point,x) -- in meters!
;
```